# Configuring SbtEclipse to get the right value for lib_managed

Tags: eclipse, sbt

I have a multi-module project that I want to import into Eclipse using [sbt eclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse). The layout is something like this:

```
workspace/myproject
workspace/myproject/foo
workspace/myproject/foo/src ...etc
workspace/myproject/bar
workspace/myproject/bar/src ...etc
workspace/myproject/lib_managed
workspace/myproject/project ... etc
```

However when I use sbt to create the eclipse project, it looks for lib_managed in

```
workspace/lib_managed
```

not

```
workspace/myproject/lib_managed
```

Is there any way to avoid this? I note [there is an option for sbteclipse called `relativeLibs`](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse) but I can't find an example of how / where you set it? I could not set it at the sbt command line like `with-source`

Comment: How do you execute the plugin on command line? What directory do you execute the plugin from? I also don't seem to meet `lib_managed` before. Why would the plugin expect the directory?!

Comment: In sbt I call 'eclipse'. I had to add the sbteclipse plugin in ~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt (or ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt in SBT 0.13). When I had one project in the workspace I could solve it by making a symbolic link from workspace/myproject/lib_managed to workspace/lib_managed but that doesn't work when you have many projects. It feels like something is going wrong because of the multiple module layout.

Comment: Can we see your build file?  This may be a bug...

Comment: Hi Jsuereth! Err no. It's not mine you see. I tried to put together a short test case but I am very new to sbt so I couldn't get it to replicate the behavior - see https://gist.github.com/butlermh/8671584 I am guessing it is due to some kind of iteraction between using the retrievedManaged option and the fact it is a multi-module project.

Comment: @jsuereth I see this with the v1.1.1 version of Spark for spark-core using Eclipse Scala-IDE 4.0.0.m1.201311011355-8ed264f https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.1.1/project/SparkBuild.scala and running eclipse with-source=true skip-parents=false

Comment: @jsuereth I used the symlink workaround for now.  To reproduce the issue, just check out Spark 1.1.1, run "eclipse with-source=true skip-parents=false", open project with Eclipse and observe errors about missing jars.

Comment: @jsuereth I ended up creating a macro to edit the generated classpath files to have non-relative, full path names to the lib_managed dir.  This made the errors go away in Eclipse and is better than a symlink since this problem could happen with more than one project.